# Fill empty values based on parent values of nested JSON Object with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm deserializing a JSON data structure like the following example with GSON:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "value": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON is mapped to the following classes:

```java
class Element {
   Integer id;
   List<SubElement> data;
   ...
}

class SubElement {
   Integer id;
   Integer value;
   ...
}
```

---

I would like to be able to fill the field `id` of the `SubElement` object based on parent `id` field using GSON at the time of deserialization.

The point of doing such a thing is that I receive this kind of JSON in several parts of my application and for instance I would like to ommit this kind of code:

```
child.setId(parent.getId());
```

---

I tried to implement a custom deserializer `JsonDeserializer<SubElement>` but I don't have access to the root element, so no access to `id`.

---

Is there any way to do this type of custom deserialization? Or should I go ahead implementing some sort of solution using `Reflection` like traversing the whole object looking for the field of interest and update it accordingly?

I'm looking for a general solution that could be valid for other nested objects lacking `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this type of custom deserialization?

Yes, but it does not necessarily needs to be a part of the Gson deserialization unless you want that thing to be centralized. You can always adjust the object after invoking its `fromJson` method (hence not that reliable). So if you think that Gson should be responsible for that, you can implement it as a post-processor:

```java
public interface IPostProcessorResolver<T> {

    @Nullable
    Consumer<T> resolvePostProcessor(@Nonnull TypeToken<?> typeToken);

}
```

```java
public final class PostProcessingTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final IPostProcessorResolver<?> resolvePostProcessor;

    private PostProcessingTypeAdapterFactory(final IPostProcessorResolver<?> resolvePostProcessor) {
        this.resolvePostProcessor = resolvePostProcessor;
    }

    public static TypeAdapterFactory create(final IPostProcessorResolver<?> resolvePostProcessor) {
        return new PostProcessingTypeAdapterFactory(resolvePostProcessor);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        @Nullable
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Consumer<T> postProcessor = (Consumer<T>) resolvePostProcessor.resolvePostProcessor(typeToken);
        if ( postProcessor == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                    throws IOException {
                delegateTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                // First, read the object
                final T object = delegateTypeAdapter.read(in);
                // Second, tell it to adjust itself
                postProcessor.accept(object);
                return object;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Then, a test:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(PostProcessingTypeAdapterFactory.create((IPostProcessorResolver<Element>) typeToken -> {
            if ( typeToken.getRawType() != Element.class ) {
                return null;
            }
            return element -> {
                if ( element.data == null ) {
                    return;
                }
                for ( @Nullable final SubElement datum : element.data ) {
                    if ( datum != null ) {
                        datum.id = element.id;
                    }
                }
            };
        }))
        .create();
...
final Element element = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Element.class);
Assertions.assertNotNull(element.data);
Assertions.assertEquals(1, (int) element.id);
Assertions.assertEquals(1, (int) element.data.get(0).id);
Assertions.assertEquals(1, (int) element.data.get(1).id);
```

Note that you can implement more complex strategies by merely implementing the `IPostProcessorResolver`: multi types support with type-resolving; reflection use; etc.

Comment: Seems like something near to what i want. Let me give a try!